# How to tie a project to a slave node in Hudson CI server?

Tags: hudson, ci-server

I'm trying to set up a Hudson slave node.  Following [Hudson -- Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294386) one eventually finds the instruction to "Check the 'Tie this project to node' check box" on a project.

I don't find this check box, nor any other way to tell a project that the new slave node exists.

How is this done?

(I have actually followed the approach of http://i-proving.com/2009/02/17/setting-up-a-hudson-slave/, using JNLP, not SSH, but still have no way to tie a project to a node.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm using Hudson with several nodes. Actually I have a checkbox named "Tie this project to a node" when I create a new project. See my screenshot :

[image]

Comment: Thanks much.  Strangely, my Hudson has everything as yours does, except the fifth checkbox is labeled "Restrict where this project can be run"

Comment: It's very strange. Are you sure that you have several nodes that are running properly ?

Comment: Yes, and using my "Restrict where this project can be run" checkbox, I'm able to tie a project to a slave node.  Your picture was a great help.

Comment: The text was modified in a recent version of Hudson.

Comment: In Jenkins 1.506 this says "Restrict where this project can be run".

Answer (score 15):

It looks like the name got changed.  When I enter a slave node in the "Restrict where the project can be run" text area it executes the project build on the slave node.