# Setting up a Hudson slave on Windows XP

Tags: windows, continuous-integration, hudson, master-slave

I set up Hudson on a Windows XP machine and got some builds and tests running on it. 
Next, I want to install the programs built on the master on other machines and do further tests there. 
On a second XP machine, I installed Hudson as a Windows service. I created a node for a slave on the master, as outlined in e.g. [Hudson -- Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294386/hudson-step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-master-and-slave-machines). I can reach that node from the slave by "http: //master:8080/computer/slavenode1/". 
According to the descriptions, I click "Launch agent from browser on slave". Firefox shows an "open with" dialog, and I select "Java(TM) Web Start Launcher (Standard)". Java is started, a small window with the title "Hudson slave agent" shows up having the message "Handshaking" on the main area, and then an error message pops up:

```
java.land.Exception: The server rejected the connection: Unauthorized access
at hudson.remoting.Engine.onConnectionRejected(Engine.java:272)
at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:233)
```

In some documentation, I read something about a certificate of the master to be trusted on the client. But no further information on how to do that, hence I could not check that.
The Windows firewall of both master and slave is switched off.

I could create a connection for a "headless slave" when Hudson is not running on the slave machine, and I additionally changed the command line from

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://localhost:8080/computer/slavenode1/slave-agent.jnlp 
to
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://master:8080/computer/slavenode1/slave-agent.jnlp
```

Do you have some hints on how to get things running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And eventually I got it running: the "slave-agent.jnlp" file contains references to "localhost" instead of "master".
I downloaded the file, replaced all references to "localhost" by "master" in Notepad, saved the file and selected "Launch" from the context menu in Windows Explorer. And voilà: after "Handshaking" the status changed to "Connected".
Sadly, the Hudson user forum is broken and creating a new user account there does not work presently...